Bayes rule and prior distribution query
The following is obtained from a research paper (page 2):
Consider that we have discretized a continuous random variable $\theta$ such that $\theta_1,...,\theta_d \in [0, \pi]$. We then have the posterior distribution given by Bayes rule
$$P(\theta_j|\mu) = \frac{P(\mu|\theta_j)P(\theta_j)}{P(\mu)},$$
where $\sum_{i}^{d}P(\theta_j|\mu)\delta \theta = 1$ and $\delta \theta = \theta_d/(d-1)$.
We calculate the prior $P(\theta_j)$ from its definition as the marginal distribution $P(\theta_j) = \sum_\mu P(\theta_j|\mu)P(\mu)$ with the sum extending over all possible measurement results $\mu$ (assumed as a discrete random variable). As $P(\mu)$ is also unknown, we can eliminate it by again inserting the marginal expression $P(\mu) = \sum_{k=1}^{d-1}P(\mu|\theta_k)P(\theta_k) \delta \theta$ which results in the implicit integral equation
$$P(\theta_j) = \sum_{\mu}P(\theta_j|\mu)\sum_{k=1}^{d}P(\mu|\theta_k)P(\theta_k)\delta \theta$$
My question is why does the summation limit change from $d-1$ for $P(\mu)$ to $d$ in the final equation of $P(\theta_j)$? My guess is that the summation limit should be $d-1$ in the final equation as well?
Thanks for any assistance.

Easy enough to explain: there's a mistake in the paper. That paper is extremely confusing to read (and fairly confused too). I think their method works (somewhat...) but their explanation is incorrect. If you want to understand Bayesian inference more, you should read better source material.

If you want to understand their paper better, then what they do is try to learn the likelihood using an arbitrary learner, by dividing a posterior (actually learned by the learned) by a prior (which I don't understand how they choose but should have been the marginal distribution in the training data, in my opinion). Learning the likelihood directly would have been easier and better-behaved.
